# pandas: Locate/Select records where a column has list of nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where few of my columns have lists of float as their value for a record.
I'm trying to locate/select all those records where say in my dataframe `df` for column `x1` the records have `[nan, nan]`

```
        x1            x2
0 [21.25, 25.45]   string1
1 [45.25, 85.45]   string2 
2   [nan, nan]     string3
3 [96.25, 79.45]   string4
4 [12.25, 65.45]   string5
5   [nan, nan]     string6
6   [nan, nan]     string7
```

I want the result:

```
        x1            x2
2   [nan, nan]     string3
5   [nan, nan]     string6
6   [nan, nan]     string7
```

I know the way to do it if there are no lists just float values for each record,
`df.loc[df['x1'].isnull()]`

But I can't seem to figure out how to do it if it's a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method:

```
print(df[df['x1'].apply(lambda x: np.isnan(x).all())])
```

Prints:

```
           x1       x2
2  [nan, nan]  string3
5  [nan, nan]  string6
6  [nan, nan]  string7
```

Answer (score 1):

You could work with numpy here to check where all values in a row are `np.nan` in one go.

*Note that this assumes all values in `x1` have the same amount of values*.

```
df[np.isnan(np.stack(df.x1.to_numpy()).astype(float)).all(1)]

           x1       x2
2  [nan, nan]  string3
5  [nan, nan]  string6
6  [nan, nan]  string7
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue. But compared to one of the other solutions there are quite a few type changes. Otherwise it works as expected.

Comment: The reason behind using numpy is efficiency. If you have a large dataframe, you should consider a vectorized approach @user9996043 , even though its slightly more verbose

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `explode`:

```
df[df['x1'].explode().isna().all(level=0)]
```

Output:

```
           x1       x2
2  [nan, nan]  string3
5  [nan, nan]  string6
6  [nan, nan]  string7
```